# Create Image of VM Instance on GCE

Tags: virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

### Context

I'm developing a web application on [Bitnami's LAPP stack deployed with Google Cloud Platform's cloud launcher](https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/bitnami-launchpad/lappstack), where 'LAPP' means Linux (Debian), Apache, PHP, PostgreSQL.

It's running on a VM instance in Google Compute Engine with the web app's data stored with local PostgreSQL. (I chose PostgreSQL because it can maintain back-end Views, but I'm considering swithing to MySQL to take advantage of Google Cloud SQL's easier backups.)

### Question

I'm attempting to [make an image](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/imagesAdd) of the VM instance's disk for back-up purposes (and in case I want to make a new instance with different API privileges). However, the source disk for an image cannot be attached to a VM instance.

**How can I temporarily detach a disk from a VM instance?**

I have already shut down the instance by SSH'ing in and using the `sudo poweroff` command.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, detaching the boot disk of a VM instance is not supported, even if the instance is stopped:

```
$ gcloud compute instances describe instance-1 --zone us-central1-f | grep 'status\|device'

  deviceName: instance-1
status: TERMINATED

$ gcloud compute instances detach-disk --device-name instance-1 --zone us-central1-f instance-1
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.detach-disk) There was a problem modifying the resource:
 - Hot-remove of the root disk is not supported.
```

I think you have two options.

**First option**: instead of an image, you can create a [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) for the disk.  The command would be something like

```
gcloud compute disks snapshot --zone us-central1-f instance-1 --snapshot-names my-snapshot
```

Unlike with images, creating a snapshot does not require that the source disk is detached.  It does not even require that the VM the disk is attached to is terminated, it may still be running, though you need to be careful with this and the safety of this can be specific to the file system type and applications you are using.  See the docs I linked above.

Once you have the snapshot, you can use it to create a disk using `--source-snapshot` flag of `gcloud compute disks create` command.  And then use the disk as the boot disk for a new VM using `--image` flag of `gcloud compute instances create` command.

**Second option**: If your primary goal is to re-create the VM instance with a different set of permission scopes, you could also do that as follows.

- Set the disk not to be auto-deleted when the VM instance is deleted:

  ```
  gcloud compute instances set-disk-auto-delete --zone us-central1-f --device-name instance-1 --no-auto-delete instance-1
  ```

  You may find [Google Cloud Shell](https://console.cloud.google.com?cloudshell=true) useful at this step in case you don't have a terminal with [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) installed readily available.
- Check that the instance does not have any disks with auto-delete on:

  ```
  $ gcloud compute instances describe --zone us-central1-f instance-1 | grep autoDelete
  - autoDelete: false
  ```

  (The command must not have any `true` values for the `autoDelete` field)
- Delete the VM instance.  Though I am a command line type of guy, I'd use Cloud Console here, just to double-check once again that the "Delete boot disk when instance is deleted" box is unchecked on the instance page before I do the deletion.  I think I'm paranoid.
- Create a new VM instance using `gcloud compute instances create` in the same zone as the original one and passing something like `--disk name=instance-1,boot=yes,auto-delete=yes` to instruct the tool to use your existing disk as the boot disk for the instance instead of creating a new one.

Practically, if my goal would be to just re-create an instance with a different set of permission scopes, I'd go with the second route, but would still create a snapshot first, just a safety measure.  Also, the second option assumes you re-create the instance in the same zone.  If you want to bring the new instance over to a different zone, the first option is the way to go.  On the other hand, the snapshots have the nice property of being differential, making them a good choice for periodic backups.